# How to get rig of strange stains/reflections from mesh on eevee engine

Tags: eevee-render-engine

i use textures from Substance Painter to make a little presentation. On her hair appears strange lights artifacts and i dont know how to deal with it. I tried to use normal map made in blender but without effect. Also i remember to invert green channel in normal map in nodes. It works properly in cycles, but i want to know how to fix it. It doesn't show in other part of body
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: a little bit more info about your setup would be helpful. Also, if you can recreate this effect in a fresh blendfile in a simple way (add a sphere with your texture or something like that), then you can share that blendfile. Also it would really help to isolate the cause

Comment: I added node setup and attach .blend

Comment: you didnt pack the textures in you problem file.

Comment: it looks to me like a clipping error of one of the maps, try to play around with a colorramp. and first try to lokate wich of the textures is the origin of the problem.

Comment: I corrected file, sorry for that. I tested it before and problem cause normal map, but i dont know why

Comment: why are your Images set to linear colors? Normalmap should be non color and the others should be color

Comment: For some reasons upload this file change it to the linear colors. I checked and i have as you told